# binding two different transforms together in silverlight 4

Tags: c#, silverlight

I try to bind a translateTransform and a compositeTransform together in silverlight 4 in the code (c#). I can't do this in xaml because the UIelements are loaded dynamically. I just need the Xoffset. The compositeTransform is the source. I have the flowing code, but it doesn't work:

```
TranslateTransform trans = new TranslateTransform();
Binding transBind = new Binding("Value");
transBind.Source = ((CompositeTransform)SchedulePanel.RenderTransform);
BindingOperations.SetBinding(trans, TranslateTransform.XProperty, transBind);
line.TextChannelName.RenderTransform = trans;
```

Thanks

Comment: So long as the child controls have either their own DataContext set, or inherit one from the parent container, there is no reason you can't have bindings in child controls. How are you loading/creating your dynamic controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since TranslateTransform is not a FrameworkElement, in order to be the target of a binding it must meet one of these conditions (from MSDN):

> In Silverlight 4, the target can also be a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject in the following cases:
>
> - The DependencyObject is the value of a property of a FrameworkElement.
> - The DependencyObject is in a collection that is the value of a FrameworkElement property (for example, the Resources property).
> - The DependencyObject is in a DependencyObjectCollection.

So try setting the **trans** TranslateTransform as the Transform of TextChannelName *before* setting the binding so that at the moment of setting the binsing, the target.

Try:

```
TranslateTransform trans = new TranslateTransform();
line.TextChannelName.RenderTransform = trans; 

Binding transBind = new Binding("Value"); 
transBind.Source = ((CompositeTransform)SchedulePanel.RenderTransform); 
BindingOperations.SetBinding(trans, TranslateTransform.XProperty, transBind);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me as though:-

```
Binding transBind = new Binding("Value");
```

should be

```
Binding transBind = new Binding("TranslateX");
```

a composite transform does not have a "Value" property.